# Dual annotations for scatter point in plotly graph using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, scatter

I designed a shiny app to plot two plotly graph.

One of the graph is a scatter plot, and the selected point would be highlighted by changing color and size. My codes are here:

```
output$ID <- renderPlotly({ # This render command makes everything inside the {} reactive (will update with changes to user input via widgets)

# Select the data for the chosen compartment using a switch statement.
# For a given input in the drop-down menu, it assigns the appropriate data frame to df to be plotted.
subject_id <- switch(input$ID,"1"=1,"2"=2,"3"=3,"4"=4,"5"=5)


g <- ggplot(Kcl_V %>% slice(-subject_id), aes(x = Vd, y = Cl)) + # Initialize ggplot object
  geom_point(colour = "#F8766D",size = 3)+
  geom_point(data = Kcl_V[subject_id, ],aes(x = Vd, y= Cl), colour = "#00BFC4", size = 4)
p <- ggplotly(g) # Convert to a plotly object.
# Doesn't create legend, but when hover over, does give label (which has to be the column name).
```

})
The information is correctly plotted, however, the selected point always has dual annotations like this:
[image]

Anyone know how to avoid this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you set the `aes` in both `ggplot()` and the 2nd call to `geom_point()`, so for all data in the 2nd `geom_point` you have 2 sets of aesthetic mappings, leading to 2 sets of tooltips.

There are 2 ways you could solve this. First, you could remove the `aes` set in `ggplot` and instead set it in each `geom_point` separately, one dataset and aesthetic mapping for the selected point and one for the non-selected points.

```
output$ID <- renderPlotly({ # This render command makes everything inside the {} reactive (will update with changes to user input via widgets)

  # Select the data for the chosen compartment using a switch statement.
  # For a given input in the drop-down menu, it assigns the appropriate data frame to df to be plotted.
  subject_id <- switch(input$ID,"1"=1,"2"=2,"3"=3,"4"=4,"5"=5)

  g <- ggplot() + # Initialize ggplot object
    geom_point(data = Kcl_V[-subject_id, ],aes(x = Vd, y= Cl),colour = "#F8766D",size = 3)+
    geom_point(data = Kcl_V[subject_id, ],aes(x = Vd, y= Cl), colour = "#00BFC4", size = 4)
  p <- ggplotly(g) # Convert to a plotly object.
  # Doesn't create legend, but when hover over, does give label (which has to be the column name).
})
```

Alternatively, you could create a boolean variable in Kcl_V that indicates if the row belongs to the selected point, and use this variable to set the color and size aesthetic mappings.

```
output$ID <- renderPlotly({ # This render command makes everything inside the {} reactive (will update with changes to user input via widgets)

  # Select the data for the chosen compartment using a switch statement.
  # For a given input in the drop-down menu, it assigns the appropriate data frame to df to be plotted.
  selected_id <- switch(input$ID,"1"=1,"2"=2,"3"=3,"4"=4,"5"=5)

  g <- ggplot(Kcl_V %>% dplyr::mutate(selected = subject_id == selected_id),aes(x = Vd, y= Cl,color = selected, size = selected)) + # Initialize ggplot object
    scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE"="#00BFC4","FALSE"="#F8766D")) +
    scale_size_manual(values = c("TRUE"=4,"FALSE"=3))
  p <- ggplotly(g) # Convert to a plotly object.
  # Doesn't create legend, but when hover over, does give label (which has to be the column name).
})
```